# How to search google scholar for singular and plural words?

Tags: research-process, google-scholar

I want to look up also the plural of my words on Google Scholar.

Here is a part of my search: "entrepreneur OR entrepreneurs".

Is there a more efficient way, for example using regex-like "entrepreneurs?"?

What about woman/women?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the alternative terms are part of a phrase, then you could use parentheses `()` and a vertical bar `|`, like `"the (woman|women)"`.

The same applies to, for instance: `"the (entrepreneur|entrepreneurs) told"`. I tested it and it works.

---

(**EDIT**: I originally wrote that the wildcard `entrepreneur*` should work, but my test was not so convincing. Thanks to lighthouse keeper's comment.)

Comment: sad that the wildcard doesn't work